# Is a value attribute required for a HTML SELECT element?

Tags: html, html-select

The select menu value posted to the server should be the same as the text in the OPTION element.

On the browser I am using, the following produce identical results.

Is the second script "correct" and cross browser supported?

```
 <select>
  <option value="AAA">AAA</option>
  <option value="BBB">BBB</option>
  <option value="CCC">CCC</option>
</select>

 <select>
  <option>AAA</option>
  <option>BBB</option>
  <option>CCC</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option) the attribute is optional as the value is inferred from the text if it is omitted

> The content of this attribute represents the value to be submitted
>   with the form, should this option be selected. If this attribute is
>   omitted, the value is taken from the text content of the option
>   element.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can omit the value attribute.

Taken from the [w3 Standards for `<option>` tags](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_option.asp):

> The  tag can be used without any attributes, but you usually need the value attribute, which indicates what is sent to the server.

A simple Google search goes a long way.

Comment: How much do you want to bet that my answer wasn't selected because I told the OP to search before asking? The truth hurts. :)

Answer (score 2):

The `value` attribute is *optional* according to the HTML 4.01 and 5 specs.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6

> value = This attribute specifies the initial value of the control. If this attribute is not set, the initial value is set to the contents of the OPTION element.

https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-option-element

> The value attribute provides a value for element. The value of an option element is the value of the value content attribute, if there is one, or, if there is not, the value of the element's text [...] attribute.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no. The `value` attribute is not *required* but definitely beneficial. Typically just another way to capture the option selected from `JS`.