# Internal server error when passing a value from a <select> in a modal via ajax

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

[image]I have a  tag inside a modal. When trying to select an option and submit, I receive a POST 500 internal server error in the browser developer mode.

The following is my app.js code :

```
$('.test').on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
     $('#join-req').modal();
      });


$('#grp-save').on('click', function () {
    $.ajax({
            method: 'POST',
            url: urlGrp,
            data: {grp: $('#grps').val(), _token: token}
        })

    .done(function () {

            $('#join-req').modal('hide');
        });
});
```

This is my select :

```
<select class="form-control" style="width:150px" name="grps" id="grps">
                        @foreach ($j_grp as $j_grps)
                        <option>{{ $j_grps->name }}</option>
                        @endforeach                            </select>
```

The following is the route :

```
<script>
        var token = '{{ Session::token() }}';
        var urlGrp = '{{ route('jmgroup') }}';
    </script>
```

And I will do a print_r in the controller as follows :

```
    public function jmGroup(Request $request)
    {

               print_r($request);

    }
```

Comment: @RiggsFolly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38854683/is-a-value-attribute-required-for-a-html-select-element

Comment: @mplungjan Thanks for that, I didn't know that, _Obviously_

Comment: Yeah, I always give values anyway in defensive coding since I am from a time where IE would return undefined on select values if the options did not have a value attribute

Comment: @mplungjan Yes rather than pleading the 5th I will go with your reason, I also am from way back when Knights were bold and IE was the reason for suicidal thoughts:)

Comment: I changed the $Request to Request, but still I'm seeing an error, and the print_r is not working. I've als added a screenshot. Thanks a lot.

Comment: ___An Error?___ Is it still the 500 error or a different error

Comment: still 500 error .. screenshot added above.

Comment: ERROR 500 means it comes form your server, screenshot your server side code and post it, we can help better

Comment: @AbdallahSakre you should go to the network tab in chrome developer console & check the response of error. That will help you to fix. Also `print_r($request);` will crash the server since it holds all the request value

Comment: Thanks a lot Naranz, that really helped.

Answer (score 1):

The error is because

```
public function jmGroup($Request $request)
```

should be

```
public function jmGroup(Request $request)
```

Note the class name, type hint, does not require a `$`